# Why does background music stops when playing an AVPlayer/AVQueuePlayer without setting AudioSession active?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

When I play an m3u8 on an AVQueuePlayer with setting the player mute, the music from another app in the background stops. I did not set AudioSession category and session as shown in the sample code.

Does the AVQueuePlayer set AudioSession category and session by default when I do `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem`? Or how does the background music stops?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import AVFoundation;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) AVQueuePlayer * player;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] init];
    [self.player setMuted:YES];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"];
//        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
//        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
    AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:URL];
    [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];

    [self.player play];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@end
```

Comment: Just found a clue here: [Although the AVFoundation playback and recording classes automatically activate your audio session](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW23). Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [AVAudioSession setCategory:withOptions:error:] method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616442-setcategory?language=objc

make sure to use AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers option.

for example:

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error: nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];

Comment: Thank you, I just found out this solution, too. And I still can not understand how does AVPlayer/AVQueuePlayer work to stop the background music without setting the category.

Comment: This is the by default action

Comment: Can you please provide the source?

Comment: did that help??

Comment: It does play video without stopping the background music, but I did not get the answer for my main question :p

Comment: I thought I already answered!
Player by default will stop any other players, unless you set AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers option

Comment: Alright. I found the source that explains the player will stop any other players by default. [Although the AVFoundation playback and recording classes automatically activate your audio session](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW23). Along with this source, this answer convinced me now.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a solution in Swift. Please note that the [methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616442-setcategory) do have a returning value.

```swift
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
```